# How to search for a specific int or string within an object?

Tags: javascript, jquery, object, find

I have a large object and am looking to find a generated number within the object without knowing it's path or location. How can I search for either the property or just the value or even a bool?

i.e. an object that has objects where a property 'version' has the value of '90'

```
var objy = {
    example: 'unknown0',
    example1: 'unknown1',
    example2: 'unknown2',
    example3: 'unknown3',
    example4: 'unknown4',
    example5: {
        prop1: 1,
        prop2: 2,
        prop3: 3,
        prop4: 4,
        prop5: {
            etc1: true,
            etc2: false,
            etc4: {
                version: 90
            }
        }
    }
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/J5Avu/

Is this even possible without know the 'tree' before-hand?

Comment: Are you just trying to determine if the given `property` and `value` combination exists anywhere in the object "tree"?

Comment: yup and if they do, where

Comment: The answer to your last question is: Yes, this is possible without knowing the "tree" beforehand.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Heres a function that basically looks through the object's properties recursively looking for the propertyName/propertyValue combination and keeps track of the "path" as it goes ([jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/J5Avu/3/)).  It returns `null` if it didn't find it.

```
function findPropertyAndValueInObject( obj, prop, value, path ) {
    if( obj[prop] === value ) {
        return path;
    }
    else {
        var foundPath = null;
        for( var thisProp in obj ) {
            var propValue = obj[thisProp];
            if( typeof(propValue) === "object" ) {
                foundPath = findPropertyAndValueInObject(propValue, prop, value, path + "." + thisProp);
                if( foundPath !== null ) {
                    break;
                }
            }
        }

        return foundPath;
    }
}

console.log( findPropertyAndValueInObject( objy, "version", 90, "objy" ) );
//prints out "objy.example5.prop5.etc4"
```

Answer (score 0):

This function find the value of a property of the given object, matching at the given string path. Here you'll find a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/5UU6h/1/) of it with your data, then here a usage into [wJs library](http://www.wexample.com/wjs/api/2.6.4/object_find). Below, there is the stand alone version.

For your usage `object_find('example5.prop5.etc4.version', object);` will return `90`

```
/**
 * Find data into an object using string path
 * like : "my.needle.name" into "haystack"
 * @param path
 * @param object object
 * @returns {*}
 */
function object_find(path, object) {
    var base = object, item;
    path = path.split('.');
    while (path.length > 0) {
        item = path.shift();
        if (base.hasOwnProperty(item)) {
            base = base[item];
            if (path.length === 0) {
                return base;
            }
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```